# Antlr4 lexer for template language without closing entity

Tags: templates, antlr4, lexer, mode

I'm trying to write template engine with antlr with such syntax(simplified):

```
<h1>Hello @bar.foo.world</h1>
<date>@bar.foo.date() {
   <span class="delimiter">/</span>
}</date>
```

Since I have mix of text and template stuff I used modes like this:

```
Start: '@' -> pushMode(TPL);
mode TPL;
//....
Identifier: [a-z] (. [a-z])* -> popMode;
```

But variable and function definition vary only by whether "(" goes after identifier or not. As I got this is stuff for parser but since I use mode in lexer I need to solve it on lexer lvl.

The options I see are:

1. use some Java inside lexer (which is bad since I would like to have multiple target platforms)
2. try put "(" into function rule (as I got it will require cut "(" from the token text later on translations stage)

Any better options?

Comment: Actually I think I meant this approach in second option. What I would like to have is kind of lookahead without consuming the characters but as I got antlr has no something like this.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see.